# Why they use "own" in this sentence : "who's father own notable history..."

Tags: single-word-requests

In the movie Tron: Legacy, there's a conversation:

I'm sure it comes as no surprise, who we have to acclaim. The head of our software design team. A man who's father **own**, uh, notable history with ENCOM, helped make this company, what it is today. Edward Dillinger.

My question is, why they use "own" in this sentence instead of using "owns" or "owned".

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to say “whose father’s own notable history” (or perhaps more likely, “whose own father’s notable history”). The rest of it is misspelt and mispunctuated too. Googling it, about half the scripts and subtitles available online seem to have the shoddy version you've found, while the other half have the version that makes sense.

Comment: Clip at https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/55e5196b-4d67-4e9a-a096-58fa9cbd0356.  It says "a man whose father's own, "uh," notable history"  ... The "uh" calls in question "notable history"--irony, sarcasm.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346460/my-own-hometown-vs-my-hometown for explanation (i.e., this is a dupe)